# Build number in SharePoint Central Admin

Tags: central-administration, patching, build-number

I have a bit confusion with the Check Product and Patch Installation page in Central Administration. I know how to check Config DB version number.

On Manage Servers in Farm it displays my SharePoint Config DB version is 15.0.4569.1000 but what are these numbers exactly indicating on this page, marked with red in below image and they both are different?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both build numbers `15.0.4569.1000` & `15.0.4571.1502` refers to your farm has been patched to Service Pack 1. you can check the corresponding release for the build numbers at [SP Build Number](https://buildnumbers.wordpress.com/sharepoint/)

Regarding The first number `15.0.4569.1000` is Service Pack 1 (replaced) that released on 2014 February 25.

Regarding The second number `15.0.4571.1502` is Service Pack 1 (re-released) that released on 2014 April 22. **Note:** re-released means SP1 has been updated for more details check [SP1 for SharePoint 2013 has been rereleased](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2014/04/22/sp1-for-sharepoint-2013-has-been-rereleased/)

**Note:** Don't trust the build number in Manage Servers in Farm, it often gives you a wrong indication about installed fixes. For more details check [SharePoint patching demystified](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2014/08/18/sharepoint-patching-demystified/)

Regarding `KB2880552`: it's the knowledge base number of the description article related to this update.

The [description article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2880552/description-of-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2013-service-pack-1-sp1) shows How to obtain and install the service pack, the fixes, and the prerequisites ...etc

See also [FIND FARM PATCH LEVEL / LATEST CUMULATIVE UPDATE THAT HAS BEEN INSTALLED ON SHAREPOINT FARM](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)

Answer (score 2):

Stefan Goßner has a great blog post on this - [SharePoint does not have a build version. Full Stop](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/08/23/sharepoint-does-not-have-a-build-version-full-stop/).

I think it is worth noting that you can gauge what patch level you're at, but each component in SharePoint has it's own build number, which can influence the farm build number.

For your image, the KB number is the knowledge base article for the specific patch. The Version number is the version of that specific component. In your case, Service Pack 1.